# Filter Json Object using Jquery

Tags: jquery, json, .net-2.0

I am working on Asp.NET (2.0). I have a json response like this.

```
{
  "0": {
    "EMPLOYEE_CODE": "049",
    "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Craig J Miller",
    "EMPLOYEE_CITY": "Tustin",
    "EMPLOYEE_STATE": "CA"
  },
  "1": {
    "EMPLOYEE_CODE": "050",
    "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Stephen B",
    "EMPLOYEE_CITY": "FOLSOM",
    "EMPLOYEE_STATE": "CA"
  },
  "2": {
    "EMPLOYEE_CODE": "051",
    "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Mithali Raj",
    "EMPLOYEE_CITY": "Glendale",
    "EMPLOYEE_STATE": "AZ"
  },
  "3": {
    "EMPLOYEE_CODE": "052",
    "EMPLOYEE_NAME": "Gordon Green",
    "EMPLOYEE_CITY": "Pheonix",
    "EMPLOYEE_STATE": "AZ"
  }
}
```

Now i want to filter the above json response by `EMPLOYEE_STATE` as the search criteria.

I am new to JSON and jQuery.

Comment: You should at least show that you put forth some effort in solving this yourself, this isn't a site for getting code written for free (or paid for that matter). Present a problem and we will help you solve it.

Comment: I agree with Kevin. Also, just use underscore.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```
function filter_by_employee_state(query, obj)
{
    var new_obj={}, total=0, query=query.toLowerCase();
    for(var i in obj)
    {
        var emp_st=obj[i].EMPLOYEE_STATE.toLowerCase();
        if(emp_st==query) { new_obj[i]=obj[i]; total++; }
    }
    if(total>0) return new_obj;
    return false;
}

// Filter the data object
var filtered_data=filter_by_employee_state('ca', data);
```

[**An Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/DADPT/2/).

Answer (score 0):

When comes down to the browser, if you're using Jquery's get or related methods it'll just become a json object.

If you know that already and just want to filter the array take a look at this: http://linqjs.codeplex.com

Although filtering it on the server maybe preferable depending on your scenario.